# firewall-cmd centos port forwarding seems not to work?

Tags: centos, firewall

currently I try to setup port forwarding for CentOS with firewall-cmd.

Currently my box has two interface: eth0, eth1.

eth0 represents the internal network and is in zone=public (default),

eth1 represents the external network and is in zone=external

currently eth1 is connected to another network which contains a router to the internet.

my external firewall looks like that:

```
external (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth1
  sources: 192.168.178.0/24
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 1194/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports: port=1194:proto=udp:toport=:toaddr=192.168.179.4
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

I also had the rule for Port 22:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=external --add-forward-port=port=22:proto=tcp:toport=22:toaddr=192.168.179.8
```

However both rules don't work, neither the 1194 nor the one with port 22.
Actually I tested if Port-Forwarding from our Router works to the machine, which in fact it does because if I setup HAPROXY to point to the other SSH machine:

```
frontend sshd
    bind 192.168.178.254:22
    mode tcp
    default_backend ssh
    timeout client 1h

backend ssh
    mode tcp
    server static 192.168.179.8:22 check
```

and removing the `port=22` rule, I can connect to it.
I actually run on a permissive selinux rule.

The public zone looks like that:

```
public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 192.168.179.0/24
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 7583/tcp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  sourceports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

Is there anything I'm missing?
I mean I also tried to make it work with iptables, but it didn't worked, at all.

`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` returns `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

The Linux Box is not the default Router for neither networks. Both have other routers in place.

Comment: The problem I have with masquerade on internal (your public) is that it mangles source IP of incoming external traffic being routed to servers. This turned my SMTP server into an open relay as it trusted all incoming traffic thinking the source was the router itself, which is internal. Yet, without masquerade, I cannot find a way for internal computers to access the public static IPs in the external zone that have ports forwarded, though it can access the internet itself without a problem, and incoming external traffic can get to the servers. If you forward incoming Internet traffic to an inte

Answer (score 2):

Looks like masquerade needs to be turned on for both networks:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=external --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-masquerade
firewall-cmd --reload
```

Answer (score 0):

zone target can be set to reject, which will block all incoming traffic except for the services and ports explicitly defined in zone config